# JQuery plugin for lightweight global events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I sometimes find myself wanting custom events on a global object with JQuery.

For example:

```
$(window).trigger('blah', {x: 'y'});
```

This plugin is designed to provide exactly that, except faster:

```
$.multicast('blah')({x: 'y'});
```

Full plugin code (minus test pages, really gotta get some qunit going on):

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var namedDelegates = {},
        guid = 0,
        multicastDelegate = function () {
            var targets = {},
                proxy = function () {
                    var args = arguments,
                        useargs = args.length > 0,
                        results = [],
                        site;
                    for (site in targets) {
                        if (targets.hasOwnProperty(site)) {
                            if (useargs) {
                                results.push(targets[site].apply(this, args));
                            } else {
                                results.push(targets[site].call(this));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (proxy.aggregate) {
                        return proxy.aggregate.call(this, results);
                    }
                    return results;
                };

            $.extend(proxy, {
                exists: function () {
                    var site;
                    for (site in targets) {
                        if (targets.hasOwnProperty(site)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                add: function (func, key) {
                    if (typeof (func) === 'string') {
                        var temp = func;
                        func = key;
                        key = temp;
                    }
                    guid += 1;
                    if (!key) {
                        key = guid;
                    }
                    targets[key] = func;
                },
                remove: function (key) {
                    if (targets.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        delete targets[key];
                    }
                },
                callsites: function () {
                    return $.extend({}, targets);
                },
                aggregate: null
            });
            return proxy;
        };

    $.multicast = function (name) {
        if (!namedDelegates[name]) {
            namedDelegates[name] = multicastDelegate();
        }
        return namedDelegates[name];
    };

    $.extend($.multicast, {
        aggregates: {
            any_or_empty: function (args) {
                var r = args.length === 0,
                    i,
                    l = args.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l && !r; ++i) {
                    r = r || args[i];
                }
                return r;
            },
            all_or_empty: function (args) {
                var r = args.length === 0,
                    i,
                    l = args.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l && r; ++i) {
                    r = r && args[i];
                }
                return r;
            },
            atLeastN: function (n) {
                return function (args) {
                    var r = 0,
                        i,
                        l = args.length;
                    if (l < n) { return false; }
                    for (i = 0; i < l && r < n; ++i) {
                        r += !!args[i] ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                    return r === n;
                };
            },
            all: function (args) {
                var r = args.length !== 0,
                    i,
                    l = args.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l && r; ++i) {
                    r = r && args[i];
                }
                return r;
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/multicast)

Eventually I'll get around to uploading this to github (I am waiting on the new plugin site). Feel free to use this.

License header is and has been since I started using this:

```
/**
* jQuery.multicast
* Copyright (c) 2008 Bill Barry - after.fallout(at)gmail(dot)com | http://16randombytes.blogspot.com
* Dual licensed under MIT and GPL.
* Date: 13 Dec 2009
*/
```

I'd prefer if you kept it if you use this code, perhaps with a link here (when I do get this on JQuery plugins, I'll link there from here and update the header).

How can I make this code better?

Comment: How come you don't use $.fn if it's a jQuery plugin?

Comment: It doesn't extend the jQuery object. It extends jQuery itself.

Comment: Wouyld be interested to see how this works wqiuth the aggregates any demos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Namespacing

There's no reason why this needs to be a jQuery plugin other than that you're using the jQuery $ as the namespace, and that you're using $.extend. You could easily make this an independent library, and use a UMD-style header to load it into whatever namespace is available.

#### Duplication

There's a lot of duplicate control flow code, especially in the aggregate functions. This is javascript: Use higher order functions! Look at using `ES5`'s [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and don't be afraid to make your own. Just make sure that you use [common idioms](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read).

#### Documentation and testing

This should go hand in hand with uploading it to github. Nobody's going to use your code unless you document it, and nobody at a serious business company is going to trust it unless you have tests. There's plenty of javascript [event](https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter)/[pubsub](https://github.com/daniellmb/MinPubSub/blob/master/minpubsub.src.js) [libraries](http://microjs.com/#pub) [to](http://microjs.com/#event) [go](https://npmjs.org/search?q=event) [around](https://npmjs.org/search?q=pub+sub).

#### Minor details

Something like this

```
var r = args.length === 0,
    i,
    l = args.length;
```

Should be more like this

```
var i,
    l = args.length,
    r = l === 0;
```